# How to print JSON Dictionary elements by index?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I wrote the next snippet:

```
do {
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    for i in 0...json.count - 1 {
        print(json[i]["title"])
     }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

I get an error in this case:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>' with an index of type 'Int'
```

I want to get elements by index. I always worked with Alamofire, but today I want to do all it by default way. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does your JSON look like? If it is a *dictionary* then it has no defined order. If it is an *array* then you should not cast it to a dictionary.

Comment: @MartinR like this - `as! [String: AnyObject]`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `json` is a dictionary (`Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`) if you want to iterate over a dictionary you should use the following syntax:

```
for (someString, someAnyObject) in json {
    print(someString, someAnyObject)
}
```

Ream more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Comment: no, Martin was right. If I want to order it, I do not need use NSDictionary. In your case I'll access to key - value, but I want to order it as `json[5]["title"]`